# Duda con dos códigos en python

Tags: python, lista, matrices, math, tuplas

Espero se encuentren bien , tengo unas dudas acerca de dos códigos y agradecería mucho si pudieran aclararlas. La primera duda tiene que ver con un código en donde se pide la desviación típica y la media una muestra de números, el código en sí considero está bien pero no entiendo por qué en la varianza se escribe un -1.

Escribir un programa que pregunte por una muestra de números, separados por comas, los guarde en una lista y muestre por pantalla su media y
desviación típica:

```
    import math 
    muestras_introducidas = [] 
    total = 0 
    muestras = int(input("¿Cuantas muestras vas a introducir?: ")) 
    varianza = 0
    x = 0

    for i in range(muestras): 
        muestra = float(input(f"¿Cuál es la muestra {i+1}?: "))  
        muestras_introducidas.append(muestra) 
    print(f"Las muestras introducidas son: {muestras_introducidas}") 

    for j in muestras_introducidas:
        total += j  
    print(f"El total es: {total}")


    media = total/len(muestras_introducidas) 
    print(f"La media de las muestras introducidas es: {media}")

    for k in muestras_introducidas:
        x += (k-media)**2 

    varianza = x/(len(muestras_introducidas)-1) #por qué -1?

    desviacion = round(math.sqrt(varianza),2)
    print(f"La desviación es {desviacion}")
```

Comment: Ese es un código, cuál es el otro?

Comment: Esto parece más un concepto de estadística que de programación. No conozco mucho al respecto, pero parece que hay [varianza de muestra y de población](https://www.google.com/search?q=varianza+muestral+y+poblacional). El `-1` corresponde a la de muestra y se conoce como [Corrección de Bessel](https://www.google.com/search?q=correcci%C3%B3n+de+bessel)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pensaba que era algo relacionado con el código en si pero ahora veo que es (como tú dices), algo más de estadística. Feliz tarde.